# RestyGWT and jerseyResponse is not Valid JSON document

Tags: gwt, jersey, jax-rs, tomcat6

gwt 2.5 with Jersey 1.17 and RestyGWT 1.3

when i call

i get the following error:

Could not parse response: org.fusesource.restygwt.client.ResponseFormatException: Response was NOT a valid JSON document

my Resource class:

```
@Path("/person")
public class PersonResource {

    private static int counter = 1;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/hello")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hallo, Seryoga";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getPersons() {

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            persons.add(new Person(counter, "name-" + counter, new Date()));
            counter++;
        }

        return persons.get(0);
    }
}
```

client interface

```
public interface PersonResourceAsync extends RestService {

    @GET
    void getPersons(MethodCallback<Person> callback);

    /**
     * Utility class to get the instance of the Rest Service
     */
    public static final class Util {

        private static PersonResourceAsync instance;

        public static final PersonResourceAsync get() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = GWT.create(PersonResourceAsync.class);
                ((RestServiceProxy) instance).setResource(new Resource(
                        GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"rest/person"));
            }
            return instance;
        }

        private Util() {

        }
    }
}
```

person class has some getter/setter for id name etc is serializable and @XmlRootElement

my web.xml contains:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Rest Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>digitronic.ems.server.filebrowser</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>

        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

and in the projekt.gwt.xml:

```
<!-- RestyGWT -->
<inherits name='org.fusesource.restygwt.RestyGWT' />
```

when i call it via
http:/localhost:8080/Projekt/rest/person i get the value in json syntax
but via restygwt i calls onError and i dont know why.

can some one help me?

Comment: Are you sure you are targetting the right URL? Did you inspect with ` F12` ?

Comment: yes because i can debug on the server when i call form the client and i get a jason object but resty cant parse it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar setup and on my side the problem was that a Date object was not transfered correct. I added an adapter for the Date object.
Just put two files in the same package where your Person class is:

```
public class MyJaxbDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String,Date>{
//standard jaxb/resty ISO8601 date format
public static final String DATEFORMAT="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";

public MyJaxbDateAdapter(){}

public Date unmarshal(String s)    throws Exception    {
    if(s==null || s.length()==0){
        return null;
    }
    return new SimpleDateFormat(DATEFORMAT, Locale.GERMANY).parse(s);
}

public String marshal(Date d)     throws Exception     {
    if(d==null) {
        return "";
    }
    return new SimpleDateFormat(DATEFORMAT, Locale.GERMANY).format(d);
}
}
```

and a file package-info.java:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters
    ({
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MyJaxbDateAdapter.class,type= java.util.Date.class)

    })
package de.company.app;
```

If this does not help please add your code for the Person class.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the following code in your entrypoint class for date objects encoded/decoded by default.

```
static {
        Defaults.setDateFormat(null);
    }
```